# Windows 8 login with Live ID without local account

Tags: login, windows-8-preview, windows-live

We have just got Windows 8 Release Preview installed in our offices. We wanted to open it up for viewing to the public and I'd like to know if there is a way to let people log in with their Windows Live ID without having to set up a user account for them beforehand? What we are after is a user being able to walk up to the PC, type in their Windows Live ID and password, and they're logged in as a default user.

Is this doable in Windows 8, and if so, how?

Comment: .Net email/password?

Comment: yes. the .Net Email/password you can add. they are worded as "Microsoft accounts" in windows 8 but are essentially just .Net passport accounts from what i can tell. (I didnt need to do anything special to my email to login)

Comment: It's called Windows Live ID now. I edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: Ahh LiveID, now it makes sense, dunno why I was thrown.  It's actually called "Microsoft Account" [now](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/faq) (changing from LiveID this year).  It hasn't been called ".Net Passport" since XP (which I had completely forgotten about). ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the current [release preview](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/release-preview) it does not seem doable to have any user with a Microsoft account just sit down and sign in to a random Windows 8 RP machine. It looks like there needs to be an Administrator for that computer to add a new user to it.  As noted in "PC Settings" for a non-admin user there is not even an option to add a new user, additionally there is no where to login using just a "Microsoft Account and a password" when no other users are logged in.

[image: PC settings showing that a user must be logged in as an admin to add any users]

Comment: Damnit, Oh well thanks for the answer. They should really put this feature in.